# Javascript converting a string variable

Tags: javascript

I got this:

```
var a = "slices: {0: {color: '#ffffff'}, 1: {color: '#fffff0'}, 2: {color: '#fff000'},3: {color: '#ff0000'}, 4: {color: '#f00000'}}";
```

You can see it's a string variable

I need this

```
draw(data, {slices: {0: {color: '#ffffff'}, 1: {color: '#fffff0'}, 2: {color: '#fff000'},3: {color: '#ff0000'}, 4: {color: '#f00000'}}, is3D: true});
```

As you see I need to give the variable without being a string, I tried doing

```
eval( "slices: {0: {color: '#ffffff'}, 1: {color: '#fffff0'}, 2: {color: '#fff000'},3: {color: '#ff0000'}, 4: {color: '#f00000'}}");
```

but didn't work and I cannot do this

```
draw(data, {a, is3D: true});
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: where is this string coming from? a fix there might be easier than a fix in the consumer.

Comment: It comes from my database and i give it to my js function by xajax.

Answer (score 3):

*Fix your string to be valid JSON first* and then:

<strike>`JSON.parse('{' + a + '}');`</strike>

**EDIT**: Antti Haapala makes a good point

`JSON.parse(a);`

Courtesy of *crispamares*:

A valid JSON is like this: `"{"slices": {"0": {"color": "a"}, "1": {"color": "#fffff0"}, "2": {"color": "#fff000"},"3": {"color": "#ff0000"}, "4": {"color": "#f00000"}}}"`

====

Use Crockford's JSON2 (http://www.json.org/js.html) if you need to support <IE8

Comment: But the code in his string is not JSON.

Comment: Then he should make it valid JSON. (assuming he has that capability)

Comment: I agree that he should, if he can. If the data comes elsewhere, the easiest way to get that to JSON is to eval it and stringify ;)

Comment: It didn't come from elsewhere, though. Look at the code under "I got this." It's just hardcoded in there.

Comment: @GGG: in his post yes...it's possible that he posted that to give context...and that isn't really the code in his application

Comment: I think if he can make that valid JSON, then he can also put the {} around it as needed ;)

Comment: The problem is that I'm using google charts api and the properly sintax to give color to the slices from a pie chart is this one. You got here the playground: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart // See the line 14 and change it for this: draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?",slices: {0: {color: '#ffffff'}, 1: {color: '#fffff0'}, 2: {color: '#fff000'},3: {color: '#ff0000'}, 4: {color: '#f00000'}} });

Comment: @Jesus: so make it an object literal then instead of a string. (but it still needs to be valid syntax)

Comment: @Jesus, what are you talking about? That function takes an object, not a string. (ed- ninja'd)

Comment: Yes I know it needs an object but I don't know how to do it, I tried var b = new Object(a); and it returns me a object but it's not working.

Comment: @Jesus well, you could store it as JSON as many people suggested, and then parse the JSON and pass the resulting object.

Comment: Yes that's what I got clear. I'm gonna try my best I don't have a high knowledge so I ask you to go through here in a bit to see if I succeeded. Thanks for everything to everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

thus do:

```
var values = eval('({' + a + '})');
draw(data, values);
```

Answer (score 1):

A valid JSON looks like this:

```
'{"slices": {"0": {"color": "a"}, "1": {"color": "#fffff0"}, "2": {"color": "#fff000"},"3": {"color": "#ff0000"}, "4": {"color": "#f00000"}}}'
```

You can use http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate your JSON and then use the JSON.parser as BLSully sugested

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt you do...

`var a = 'draw(data, {slices: {0: {color: a}, 1: {color: '#fffff0'}, 2: {color: '#fff000'},3: {color: '#ff0000'}, 4: {color: '#f00000'}}, is3D: true})';`

then
`eval(a);`

Why would that not work?

Comment: Didn't work for me, try it yourself: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = eval("google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Task', 'Hours per Day'],['Work', 11],['Eat', 2],['Commute', 2],['Watch TV', 2],['Sleep', 7]])");
  var tittleChart = "So, how was your day?";

  

  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    var a = 'draw(data, {slices: {0: {color: a}, 1: {color: '#fffff0'}, 2: {color: '#fff000'},3: {color: '#ff0000'}, 4: {color: '#f00000'}}, is3D: true})';
  eval(a);
}
​

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your `a` a json object, and then add the `is3D` property to it?

```
var a = {slices: {0: {color: a}, 1: {color: '#fffff0'}, 2: {color: '#fff000'},3: {color: '#ff0000'}, 4: {color: '#f00000'}}};
if(itNeedsToBe3D) a.is3D = true;     
else a.is3D = false;
draw(data, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` as shown in many answers. You can also try a JSON parser like https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js

or you can use a `setTimeout`

```
function draw(a, b){
    console.log(a, b);
}

var data = "sample data";

var a = "slices: {0: {color: a}, 1: {color: '#fffff0'}, 2: {color: '#fff000'},3: {color: '#ff0000'}, 4: {color: '#f00000'}}";

setTimeout("draw(data, {" + a + "});", 100);
```